# Download and Replace running executable file in java

Tags: java, swing, jar, exe

It is possible to 'grab' a file from online (the Internet), such as http://www.example.com/information.html. I know there are several methods for grabbing and reading online files (URLs) line-by-line and there is a way to just download and save the file using Java:

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.website.com/information.html");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

But which is the best way to download an exe/jar file from the webpage/update site?

However my final aim is to design an update facility. Download new file (exe/jar) exactly in my running (exe/jar) location and auto open when download task will be complete. And than call something from running execution file(exe/jar):

```
System.exit(0);
```

I think if I can delete previous exe/jar file when new exe/jar start from the same previous application location. Then it may be simply replaced. Note that I  want to replace other file like bundle jre/lib.

Is it a right task to do or are there any simple way for that?

Comment: Are you wishing to implement an 'update' facility in your program?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use existing frameworks instead of reinventing automatic update for Java applications.

Try the Java Web Start: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml

> The Java Web Start software allows you to download and run Java
>   applications from the web. The Java Web Start software: Provides an
>   easy, one-click activation of applications Guarantees that you are
>   always running the latest version of the application Eliminates
>   complicated installation or upgrade procedures

Also checkout the SO tag:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info

Comment: See also the [Java Web Start info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) here at SO.

Comment: IS this applicable for bundle jre system. However my application is deploy-able. Mini short desktop application.

Comment: Java web start is interesting. I hear it before but now check it seriously ....@Maciej Lach

Comment: You can specify the required version of the JRE in the JNLP file.

Please refer to the FAQ page for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html